# Different double number formatting between server and ASP.Net MVC client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I have two properties in my Model defined as type double.

```
public double MapLatitude { get; set; }
public double MapLongitude { get; set; }
```

I am displaying them in my MVC View with the following Razor syntax:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MapLatitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MapLatitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MapLatitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MapLongitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MapLongitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MapLongitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

In the database (SQL Table) the columns are defined as "float", where the values are -33.9381288 and 18.8608831 respectively.

When the page is requested from the server, the values are displayed as follows:
[image: Initial Display on Page Load]

Note the comma's.

When I post the page back to the server, without any editing, the client-side validation stops the post-back (confirmed by using F12 dev tools), and displays as follows:
[image: Save without editing values]

When I edit the values to replace the `,` with a `.` then the client-side validation passes, and I can post to the server.

However, I then get the following server-side validation failure:
[image: Server validation result]

Please help me understand what is going on here?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have worded the statements in the last 3 paragraphs correctly (e.g. unless you have reconfigured the `$.validator`, the _The field must be a number_ validation message will only be displayed if you use `,`, not `.`)

Comment: You're right...my wording was off-track.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The issue is that your server has a culture that has `,` as the decimal separator, but `jquery.validate.js` validates numbers based on a `.` as the decimal separator. You can use the [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin, otherwise you need to reconfigure the `$.validator`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke that makes sense.  However, I'm looking at my Windows Server 2012 Regional Settings, and am seeing `.` for the decimal character.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is in your web.config.cs file? - I suspect you have specified a culture there -  `<system.web><globalization culture="???" uiCulture="???" />` Either that or you specifically setting it somewhere else (e.g. in `global.asax.cs`)

Comment: nuts...a search within my project for "globalization" returns no results in any files.

Comment: You can always check the current culture with `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Comment: @ShawndeWet The regional settings show the settings for your user account. ASP.NET will take the settings from the system account. There's a button to copy the current settings to the system account on the "Administrative" page.